# Add GeoJson variable to GoogleMap per addGeoJson

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

What I want:

- extract the lat,lon values from a json into a new variable which is build up like a GeoJson
- load the new variable to the GoogleMap and create a polygon

This is the json, which contains the needed lat, lon values:

```
{
"rangemap": {
    "rangemaps": [
        {
            "polyline": [
                {
                    "lat": 48.1914210319519,
                    "lon": 11.3745188713074
                },
                {
                    "lat": 48.1789970397949,
                    "lon": 11.3705492019653
                },
                ... and so on
```

This is my variable which I want to load to the map:

```
var rangemap_eco = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
             "coordinates": [

             ]
        }
      }
    ]
};
```

With this code I extract the coordinates from the json to the "coordinates"-array in my variable:

```
$scope.parseRM_eco = function(){
    var first;
    var last;

    for(var z=0; z < vm.rangespider.rangemap.rangemaps[0].polyline.length; z++) {
        first = vm.rangespider.rangemap.rangemaps[0].polyline[z].lon;
        last = vm.rangespider.rangemap.rangemaps[0].polyline[z].lat;
        arr[z] = '['+first+','+last+']';
    }
    rangemap_eco.features[0].geometry.coordinates.push(arr);
    console.log(rangemap_eco);
}
```

With **map.data.addGeoJson(rangemap_eco);** I load the variable to the map.

But always I get an error
"Error: in property "features": at index 0: in property "geometry": in property "coordinates": at index 0: at index 0: not an Array"

I really don't know where's the mistake....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr[z] = '['+first+','+last+']';
```

should be

```
arr[z] = [first, last];
```

or better

```
arr.push([first, last]);
```

i.e. `"coordinates"` is an array of arrays

```
coordinates: [
    [lon, lat], [lon, lat], ... etc
]
```

Comment: I got it just before, then i read your answer and it was the same solution :D but thanks, that was the right answer.